# Android SDK Setup.exe will not run

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, setup.exe

Running XP sp3 when i click SDK Setup.exe command line promt comes up and goes away fast and nothing else happens is there a fix for this ?

Comment: Run it from an open command window and see what comes up.

Comment: same thing from cmd line it just flashes something really quick and goes aways any other suggestions thank you ppl for you help

Comment: If nothing prints to the command window, then check the event logs.

Comment: What is the download link you downloaded from? It seems that the *setup.exe* you are selecting, might be used elsewhere in another executable and isn't the setup executable you need to run.

Comment: got the latest android sdk kit from the android site: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
and the .zip file :
android-sdk_r04-windows.zip

Comment: ok cleared the event viewer and clicked on the SDK Setup.exe nothing came up under the event viewer still blank from when i cleared it

Comment: "same thing from cmd line it just flashes something really quick and goes away"  sure doesn't sound like you are really running it from the command prompt.

Comment: a walk threw of what im getting from the start

start button, run, cmd, 
C:\Documents and Settings\computernamexxx> cd C:\android-sdk-windows,
C:\android-sdk-windows> start SDK Setup.exe 

then just a quick flash and nothing

Comment: Could it be a permissions thing? Is your anti virus software not allowing you run to executables or something?

Comment: nope running as admin no anti virus software

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with it but also when i went into the cmd promt going to 
cd C:\android-sdk-windows\tools> android.bat 
and i get the following:
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
startinf Android SDK Updater
"xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batcg file.
SWT fold '' does not exist
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

Comment: That is extremely odd, not to question integrity but when you run *SDK Setup.exe*, when you hit **alt+tab** there are no open windows showing a setup dialog?

Comment: Do you have java runtime environment and/or the java sdk installed?

Comment: correct nothing under alt+tab

Comment: yes have java went to the site (http://www.java.com/en/download/chrome.jsp?locale=en&host=www.java.com:80) and got the latest Download Java 6 Update 18

Comment: Do you have JRE? I just performed the same steps you did, located my *tools* folder and ran `android.bat` just fine.

Comment: alright try again 2mrow going out to watch the game thank you though all for your help ill be back again 2mrow

Comment: ya i have the java icon running in the bottom right conner

Comment: This is probably more suited to SuperUser due to it being to do with software issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my own fix and recommending it to others save SDK kit unzip to C:\ then 1.) download the latest java currently java 6.0.18 from --> java web site save and run (I used c:\ for file locations to save and run from) 2.) download the latest "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"  from --> eclipse org downloads site 3.) go to my computer c:\ --> C:\Program Files\Java copy the jre6 folder or jre...what ever version you may have paste the folder into the folder name C:\eclipse rename the folder from jre6 to just "jre" this will allow eclipse to run, in eclipse click on the help tab click install new software add location http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ ok do restart go back into eclipse go to window tab preferences, expand android, browse c:\android-sdk-windows ok, window tab Android SDK and AVD manager, Available packages, select all, update, in same area go to virtual devices, new, name: Hi target: android 2.1, create AVD, Select and start, now you will have android 2.1 emulator working

Comment: just searching around and found this how to instructions

http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=34021

up to date on how to and pic by pic instruction also if you click at the bottom of the page on how to install android 2.1 and eclipse

Comment: http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-setup-android-development_23.html -- pic by pic instructions kudos to the person who made these  (although they did not show the moving of the jre6 folder and renaming to jre for the java and eclipse program to run correctly

Answer (score 4):

try making empty folders named 'platforms' and 'add-ons' without quotations in your android-sdk-windows folder and then running sdk setup.exe
worked for me just now

Answer (score 0):

I just download the .zip file, opened the file and double-clicked the *SDK Setup.exe* and it loaded fine. A setup window popped up in the background, that does not happen to you at all?

#### EDIT:

Take a look into [**Installing the Android SDK**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) and look over the [**System Requirements**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) and make sure you have both JDK 5 or JDK 6 (*which you do*) and [**JRE 6**](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)

Comment: nope i do not get the setup window just goes blanks after a quick flash of something

Comment: i erased it re-download the android-sdk_r04-windows.zip unzipped it clicked the SDK Setup.exe still same thing nothing but the quick flash and nothing

Comment: also tryied putting in c:\windows\temp and tryed to run from that also still nothing that way as well just the quick flash and nothing

Comment: Did a good ole restart work? Something doesn't seem right, it should load fine.

Comment: tried the restart also same thing just a flash of something then nothing

Answer (score 0):

Run it from the System command prompt not the User command prompt, not sure if thats really what its called, but there are 2 separate command prompts.  You want the one that has higher privelages.

***UPDATE***

Is your computer able to connect to https?  That was an issue that was holding me back from installing android at first, however it is appropriate for the command prompt to disappear immediately.

Comment: i also tried that right click on the SDK Setup.exe icon run as admin. still same thing just a quick flash of something then blank again